# How to do a fixed sprite (that don't move with my camera) in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

How can i do a fixed sprite that don't move with my camera (for example: a life bar in the left up corner)?

I have already tried  to do this in the hard way and i would like to see if there is a simple way to do this.

Is there a simple way to do that or i need to do this in relative to the player position?

And i am sorry for my broken english, I would be very grateful to those who answer me.

thankyou.

Comment: not sure if this is best, but maybe two cameras one for HUD and one for everything else that moves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually for the task of UI you would use an extra scene2d [`Stage`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d) and implement custom subclasses [`Actor`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html) which you add to the `Stage` and set their fixed position via `Actor.setPosition()`. There are already several predefined UI elements in the [scene2d.ui](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui) package. To simulate a healthbar you could either use a `ProgressBar`, or you implement your own `HealthBar extends Actor`, which renders a `Sprite` of your choice.

The stage is stationary by default and has its own `Camera`. As long as you do not manipulate that camera anyhow, you can just draw the stage with all elements via `stage.draw()` and it will always remain at the same place (what you would expect from an ingame HUD).